# "Bundle up" or "wear warm clothing"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Dictionaries say that "bundle up" means "put on warm clothing" or "dress warmly". I need to know how do the sentences below differ in meaning:

> - It's very cold outside. **Bundle up**.
> - It's very cold outside. **Wear warm clothing**.

To me they both are common and mean the same thing, but I guess "bundle up" is more about the quantity of the warm clothes you put on and "put on warm clothing" implies the type of clothes that you should put on (here, warm clothes).

Please let me know how would you interpret them?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a point - *bundle up* can be thought of as *put on a lot of layers*, while *wear warm clothing* might mean *put on thick and insulating clothing*. But *bundle up* could also just mean *put on a warm jacket* - and I think this phrase is more colloquial. *Dress warmly*, which you also mentioned, is pretty much the same. I don’t think there’s much difference among the three phrases in practice.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, "**bundle up**" implies **a lot warm clothes** (see the definition of the [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bundle-up)), while "wear warm clothing" doesn't necessarily imply a lot of things to wear (however, the person who this is said to may still decide to put on a few warm things - it's often the case, but the speaker just says "your clothes should be warm," "make sure what you wear is warm").

It's also correct to say that to bundle up is to dress oneself or another (typically a **child**) into heavy winter clothing or outerwear ([source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bundle+up)):

> It's freezing out, so bundle Janie up in her parka, scarf, and boots—and don't forget her hat and gloves! *(note the number of things)*